# Hashicorp Vault configuration file with default secret path (v1)

Tags: docker, hashicorp-vault

I am working with [Vault](https://vaultproject.io) for my project and using the [Go API](https://github.com/hashicorp/vault/tree/master/api).

Currently the API only supports `/v1` paths, which is fine. My problem is that in my development configuration I have a `docker-compose.yml` file that is set up with a simple configuration that is as follows:

```
version: '3.7'

services:
  my-vault:
    image: library/vault:1.4.0
    container_name: my-vault
    cap_add:
      - IPC_LOCK
    environment:
      VAULT_DEV_ROOT_TOKEN_ID: devroot
      VAULT_DEV_LISTEN_ADDRESS: 0.0.0.0:8200
    ports:
      - 8200:8200
```

When I manually create my secret engine via the UI (and explicitly set it to V1) I can use my code just fine. I simply set the data and the Go library works like a charm:

```
client, err := vault.NewClient(vault.DefaultConfig())
if err != nil {
    panic(err)
}

myMapValues := map[string]interface{}{}
myMapValues["mykey"] = "someSecretValue"

_, err := client.Logical().Write("myV1SecretPath/hello", myMapValues)
if err != nil {
    panic(err)
}
```

In the Docker container I see:

```
/ # ps aux | grep vault
    6 vault     0:07 vault server -config=/vault/config -dev-root-token-id=devroot -dev-listen-address=0.0.0.0:8200 -dev
```

I see in there that the configuration location is set to the directory `/vault/config` which, by default, contains nothing. Reading the [Server Configuration documentation](https://www.vaultproject.io/docs/configuration) I do not see a way to specify a default configuration for secrets.

I would like to add a configuration file that emulates this command:

```
vault secrets enable -address=http://127.0.0.1:8200 -version=1 -path=myV1SecretPath kv
```

Is this possible via a configuration option or do I just need to build my own Docker image in order to accomplish this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That cannot be done with a configuration file - enabling an engine is done on a running server, while the config file only configures basic server behaviour - interface to listen on, where the data is stored, etc. Things that make sense at start-up.

Meanwhile, the server can't access the storage at startup because it is sealed (in your case it is running in dev mode, so will actually start unsealed, but that is not the general case that Vault is designed for).

You will need to add this call yourself, either to a customised Docker image (shouldn't be too difficult), or as part of a script that wraps your docker-compose call.

Comment: Yep, I was trying to avoid the customized Docker image if possible and do it in a more idiomatic fashion to Vault. I didn't even think of the *SEALED* aspect, which makes complete sense. Thanks.